# How to align items to the top when using css inline-blocks?

Tags: html, css

I want to align items to the top, even above what `vertical-align:top` gives you. Here's an example

http://jsfiddle.net/fqw1dsj6/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="small"></div>
    <div class="big"></div>
    <div class="small"></div>
    <div class="small"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.container{ 
    border: 1px black solid;
    width: 320px;
    height: 120px;    
}

.small{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40%;
    height: 30%;
    border: 1px black solid;
    background: aliceblue;   
    vertical-align:top;
}

.big {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px black solid;
    width: 40%;
    height: 50%;
    background: beige;  
    vertical-align:top;  
}
```

It ends up looking like

[image]

however I am looking for the cleanest technique for pushing blocks up to make it look more like

[image]

Is there some new modern technique/api to do this?

Thanks

Comment: You could look into using `display: grid` That's about the best way to get what you want.

Answer (score -2):

> *Is there some new modern technique/api to do this?*

Yes there is.

You'll need to use **CSS Grid**.

Then, the property you're looking for is: `grid-auto-flow: dense;`

---

**More Information:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow

---

**Added:**

I interpreted your example as a **2x5 grid** *(2 columns, 5 rows)* and the approach I have proposed above is based on that.

Comment: grid-auto-flow:dense cannot achieve such configuration. What he want to achieve isn't *really* a grid

Comment: Depends how strict the dimensions in the images are.

Comment: can you show an example using the dense prop?

Comment: Yes, there is an example by MDN, here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow

Comment: It just fills in empty cells in grid, it doesn't change the grid shape to be irregular which is what im asking to do.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following what you mean by _irregular_ grid-shape, unless @TemaniAfif has it right and basically what you want to achieve isn't really a grid. I saw it as a 2x5 grid, but maybe I was misreading it.